# Inserting from MS SQL Server to MySQL database, but writes blank line

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure that inserts data from the MSSQL DB tables to my MySQL database.

I followed the procedure below using a linked server.

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (MYSQLPROVIDER, 'SELECT * FROM Table_MySQL')
  SELECT * FROM Table_SQL
```

But it inserts lines with white in the null and null fields in the other fields.

It should look like this:
[Select in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93U2z.png)

It's like this:
[How it works in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqMCY.png)

What can it be?
I would be very grateful. Thank you.

PS.: Thanks for adjusting my post

Comment: Post a picture of your current output and the expected output you want

Comment: Thanks for adjusting my post, included.